# ElementTree find() always returns "None" Cisco iOS xe

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

When using find function always none is returned

I've tried differents types of tags and none is always returned.

This is the XML response i'm getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rpc-reply xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="urn:uuid:62b25025-051e-4cd7-ad9f-ab0d5e21b634">
   <data>
      <native xmlns="http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-native">
         <interface>
            <GigabitEthernet>
               <name>1</name>
               <ip>
                  <address>
                     <dhcp />
                  </address>
               </ip>
               <mop>
                  <enabled>false</enabled>
                  <sysid>false</sysid>
               </mop>
               <negotiation xmlns="http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-ethernet">
                  <auto>true</auto>
               </negotiation>
            </GigabitEthernet>
         </interface>
      </native>
   </data>
</rpc-reply>
```

This is the find statement im using.

```
address = get_reply.data.find('{http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-ethernet}interface')
```

I expect to get the tag.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what "tag" do you want to get? there are few more infos inside the `interface` entry.

Comment: Is this the Python standard-library ElementTree? (Which version?) The lxml implementation? I'd like to be sure I'm testing the same version you're asking about. Making your [mcve] include the `import` lines and actual parse operations (maybe moving the XML into the code as a constant string, to make that code copy-to-paste-to-test) can help to answer some of those questions, btw.

Comment: @MigB id like to get the <ip> tag, to see the ip information. Thanks

Comment: @CharlesDuffy im using lxml==4.2.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here (The code is not using any external library - just core python)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rpc-reply xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="urn:uuid:62b25025-051e-4cd7-ad9f-ab0d5e21b634">
   <data>
      <native xmlns="http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-native">
         <interface>
            <GigabitEthernet>
               <name>1</name>
               <ip>
                  <address>
                     <dhcp />
                  </address>
               </ip>
               <mop>
                  <enabled>false</enabled>
                  <sysid>false</sysid>
               </mop>
               <negotiation xmlns="http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-ethernet">
                  <auto>true</auto>
               </negotiation>
            </GigabitEthernet>
         </interface>
      </native>
   </data>
</rpc-reply>'''


root = ET.fromstring(xml)
interface = root.getchildren()[0].getchildren()[0].getchildren()[0]
print(interface)
gigabit_ethernet_name = interface.getchildren()[0].getchildren()[0].text
print('gigabit_ethernet_name: {}'.format(gigabit_ethernet_name))
```

output

```
<Element '{http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-native}interface' at 0x023E3A20>
gigabit_ethernet_name: 1
```

Comment: thanks @balderman for taking the time to reply, sorry guys but im new to this :), when i try to print the response as text, i see only blank. 

`>>> print(interface.text)
>>> `

Comment: Interface has no text. The elements under it have.

Comment: @Erick The code was updated and it shows the value of GigabitEthernet name

Comment: saw it, thanks a lot! what if i want to get all the tags inside the <interface>? for example:

`<GigabitEthernet>
               <name>1</name>
               <ip>
                  <address>
                     <dhcp />
                  </address>
               </ip>
               <mop>
                  <enabled>false</enabled>
                  <sysid>false</sysid>
               </mop>
               <negotiation xmlns="http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-ethernet">
                  <auto>true</auto>
               </negotiation>
            </GigabitEthernet>`

Answer (score 0):

`find`, on its own, doesn't recurse. Using `ETXPath` lets you get recursion (using `//`) *and* specify the namespace inline:

```py
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> root = lxml.etree.fromstring('''
... <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
... <rpc-reply xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="urn:uuid:62b25025-051e-4cd7-ad9f-ab0d5e21b634">
...    <data>
...       <native xmlns="http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-native">
...          <interface>
...             <GigabitEthernet>
...                <name>1</name>
...                <ip>
...                   <address>
...                      <dhcp />
...                   </address>
...                </ip>
...                <mop>
...                   <enabled>false</enabled>
...                   <sysid>false</sysid>
...                </mop>
...                <negotiation xmlns="http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-ethernet">
...                   <auto>true</auto>
...                </negotiation>
...             </GigabitEthernet>
...          </interface>
...       </native>
...    </data>
... </rpc-reply>
... '''.strip().encode('utf-8')
>>> lxml.etree.ETXPath('//{http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-native}interface')(root)
[<Element {http://cisco.com/ns/yang/Cisco-IOS-XE-native}interface at 0x101cc8410>]
```

Also, note that the correct namespace for what you wanted to retrieve was the one ending in `interface`, not `native`.

Comment: Good, i tested it and saw it, but in the book im reading, the author uses `find()` and get back everything inside the specified tag, including other tags.